# CryptographicException when accessing Certificate of Smart Card

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509certificate, smartcard

I'm developing a C# class called `SmartCardService` for the company I work at.
Desktop applications use virtual and physical smart cards to communicate with a embedded PLC also developed by our Company. Certificates for this purpose are issued by our IT specifically for every user.

The `SmartCardService` provides basic functionality for encrypting, decrypting and signing data and verifying signatures.

```
public sealed class SmartCardService : ISmartCardService
{
    private RSACryptoServiceProvider CryptoServiceProvider { get; }

    public SmartCardService(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        if(certificate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("missing certificate");
        CryptoServiceProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)Certificate.PrivateKey;
    }

    public byte[] EncryptData(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        return CryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(data, false);
    }

    public byte[] DecryptData(byte[] cipher)
    {
        if (cipher == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("cipher");
        return CryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(cipher, false);
    }

    public byte[] SignData(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            return CryptoServiceProvider.SignData(data, sha256);
        }
    }

    public bool VerifySignature(byte[] data, byte[] signature)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        if (signature == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("signature");

        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            return CryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData(data, sha256, signature);
        }
    }
}
```

The certificate itself is provided by another component `CertificateProvider` in the composition root of the application (which later also disposes of the certificate object). It simply selects the first certificate issued by our company for the user.

```
public sealed class CertificateProvider
{
    public X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromStore(string subjectName)
    {
        using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            return store.Certificates
                    .Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "<COMPANY NAME>", true)
                    .Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subjectName, true)
                    .Cast<X509Certificate2>()
                    .First();

        }
    }
}
```

The problem happens in the following example:

```
// example data encryption and decryption
var service = new SmartCardService(certificate);
var data = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
var encryptedData = service.EncryptData(data);              // prints a 256 byte long array of hex values
var decryptedData = service.DecryptData(encryptedData);     // prints the original data: 00-01-02-03-04-05-06-07
```

On Windows 10, everything runs fine. The results are as expected.

However, on Windows 7, the same code results in a `CryptographicException` as soon as this line is hit in the constructor of the `SmartCardService` class:

```
CryptoServiceProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)Certificate.PrivateKey;
```

The exception has the following stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: System cannot find the specified file.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
```

I still haven't found the cause of this problem.  If somebody could help me with this problem, I would be very very grateful.

PS: I found an old [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/11/16/opps-system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/) with the same exception stating problems with storing the keys in the user's profile. I'm not sure if this relates to the problem I am facing.

Comment: If it really tries to access a file-system file you should use Sysinternals ProcessMonitor to see what actual non-existing file it tries to access. May be it helps you to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: One possibility is on Win7 you have a CNG driver, but no CAPI driver.  You should really use `GetRSAPrivateKey()` (which returns an `RSA` you shouldn't cast to a more specific type) to let it be CAPI or CNG as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [bartonjs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6535399/bartonjs) advice and used the `GetRSAPrivateKey()` [RSACertificateExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.rsacertificateextensions.getrsapublickey?view=netframework-4.8) method. This solved the problem.

If anybody ever has the same or a similar problem, below is the refactored class that works now on both Windows 10 and Windows 7.

```
public sealed class SmartCardService : ISmartCardService
{
    private X509Certificate2 Certificate { get; }
    private RSA Rsa { get; }

    public SmartCardService(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        Certificate = certificate ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("missing certificate");
        Rsa = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey() ?? throw new CryptographicException("certificate has no private key");
    }

    public byte[] EncryptData(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

        return Rsa.Encrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
    }

    public byte[] DecryptData(byte[] cipher)
    {
        if (cipher == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("cipher");

        return Rsa.Decrypt(cipher, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
    }

    public byte[] SignData(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        return Rsa.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    }

    public bool VerifySignature(byte[] data, byte[] signature)
    {
        if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        if (signature == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("signature");
        return Rsa.VerifyData(data, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    }
}
```